# How to search and replace , between " " in unix

Tags: linux, unix, command

Input:

```
20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
Exchange subsidary,Passed,00021423SNG,R-JAM-05-03,US (First Exchange),20000000,"JUDICIARY, STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.212.12/30,00052312SNG,R-JPODIU-023-07,US (First Exchange) ,20000000,"JUDICIARY, STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.224.213/30
```

Ideal result:

```
20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2     
Exchange subsidary,Passed,00021423SNG,R-JAM-05-03,US (First Exchange),20000000,"JUDICIARY STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.212.12/30,00052312SNG,R-JPODIU-023-07,US (First Exchange) ,20000000,"JUDICIARY STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.224.213/30
```

How do I get rid of the comma between the quotes?
There are also lines without the comma between the quotes.

I need to remove the comma inside ,`"JUDICIARY, STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)"` (both occurrences on a single line).

And [some lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587214/how-to-search-and-replace-between-in-unix#comment60773687_36587346) have several fields with commas between double

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We will need more info to help you. Are these data in a file, database, online source or what? What have you tried so far?

Comment: he "xxxx,xxxx" is in the 7 and 8 field and it is using "," as separator. What i want is to remove the comma inside the quotes, only if they are present and all the infomation are stored in a txt file.

Comment: remove it or replace both is fine. Only those within " " thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script which demos how you can do it — welcome to the world of `goto` in `sed`.  This is written using BSD `sed` which uses `-E` to enable extended regular expressions; GNU `sed` uses `-r` for the same task.

```
sed -E -e 's/^/A: /p; s/^A: /B: /' \
       -e ':again' \
       -e 's/^(([^"]*|"[^",]*")*)("[^"]*),([^"]*")/\1\3\4/' \
       -e 't again' \
       data
```

Assuming that the data is in a file called `data`.  The first `-e` simply echoes the original input prefixed with `A:` and then changes the prefix to `B:`.  This is debugging material.  The second `-e` makes a label `again` to which it is possible to jump.  The fourth `-e` jumps to the `again` label if the previous step made a substitution.

All the excitement is in the third `-e`.  The pattern looks for the start of line, followed by a sequence of zero or more occurrences of either a sequence of
"not double quotes" or "double quote followed by zero or more 'not double quote' and a double quote", followed by a double quote, a sequence of 'not double quote's, a comma, more 'not double quotes' and a double quote.  This is replaced by the prefix, the part before the comma between double quotes and the part after the comma between double quotes.

Given a data file:

```
2000,"xxxx,xxxx",192.168.3.2
2000,"xx,xx,xx",192.16.3.2
2000,"xxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2,"yyyyy,yyyyy"
20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
201,"x,x",192.168.3.2,"y,y","aaaa,cccc,dddd",192,"zzzz",234
201,"x,x",192.168.3.2,"yyy"
201,"xx",192.168.3.2,"yyy",2211
201,"xxx",192.168.3.2,"y,y"
201,"xxx",192.168.3.2,"yyy"
201,"x,x",192.168.3.2,"y,y"
Exchange subsidary,Passed,00021423SNG,R-JAM-05-03,US (First Exchange),20000000,"JUDICIARY, STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.212.12/30,00052312SNG,R-JPODIU-023-07,US (First Exchange) ,20000000,"JUDICIARY, STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.224.213/30
```

the script produces the output:

```
A: 2000,"xxxx,xxxx",192.168.3.2
B: 2000,"xxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
A: 2000,"xx,xx,xx",192.16.3.2
B: 2000,"xxxxxx",192.16.3.2
A: 2000,"xxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
B: 2000,"xxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
A: 20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2,"yyyyy,yyyyy"
B: 20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2,"yyyyyyyyyy"
A: 20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
B: 20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
A: 20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
B: 20000000,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",192.168.3.2
A: 201,"x,x",192.168.3.2,"y,y","aaaa,cccc,dddd",192,"zzzz",234
B: 201,"xx",192.168.3.2,"yy","aaaaccccdddd",192,"zzzz",234
A: 201,"x,x",192.168.3.2,"yyy"
B: 201,"xx",192.168.3.2,"yyy"
A: 201,"xx",192.168.3.2,"yyy",2211
B: 201,"xx",192.168.3.2,"yyy",2211
A: 201,"xxx",192.168.3.2,"y,y"
B: 201,"xxx",192.168.3.2,"yy"
A: 201,"xxx",192.168.3.2,"yyy"
B: 201,"xxx",192.168.3.2,"yyy"
A: 201,"x,x",192.168.3.2,"y,y"
B: 201,"xx",192.168.3.2,"yy"
A: Exchange subsidary,Passed,00021423SNG,R-JAM-05-03,US (First Exchange),20000000,"JUDICIARY, STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.212.12/30,00052312SNG,R-JPODIU-023-07,US (First Exchange) ,20000000,"JUDICIARY, STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.224.213/30 
B: Exchange subsidary,Passed,00021423SNG,R-JAM-05-03,US (First Exchange),20000000,"JUDICIARY STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.212.12/30,00052312SNG,R-JPODIU-023-07,US (First Exchange) ,20000000,"JUDICIARY STATE COURTS (STATE COURTS)",112.78.224.213/30
```

Be aware: this is hard.  If you have an option, use a tool that is aware of CSV formatting.  For example, Python comes with a CSV module; Perl has `Text::CSV` (and subsidiary modules `Text::CSV_PP` and `Text::CSV_XS`) which can handle this; there are custom tools for manipulating CSV files.

Also be aware that Microsoft supports slightly different notations from [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), which is the Internet World's attempt to rationalize what Microsoft uses (to a first approximation).

Comment: As always, an excellent post. Agree about using correct tools. To the O.P.,  I would also recommend trying to re-create the data, correctly formatted. Often times that is the fastest solution. Good luck to all.